Error when using popBackStack, "No destination with route is on the NavController's back stack."
need a little help.
I want to view the AlertDialog when the user uses the back button that asks him if he really wants to leave current screen, but I am getting an error on clicking the button from that alert:
IllegalArgumentException:  No destination with route CreatingAlbumGraph is on the NavController's back stack. The current destination is Destination(0x9993fa65) GalleryDestination

On Logcat, I'm getting "$$ albumSetup remember parent entry" when entering AlbumSetupRoute and when clicking the leave button on alert, so probably somehow my NavController is trying to navigate again to AlbumSetupScreen after popBackStack().
AlbumSetup.kt:
@Serializable
object AlbumSetupDestination

@Composable
fun AlbumSetupRoute( navController: NavHostController ) {
    val parentEntry = remember(navController.currentBackStackEntry) {
        Log.d(TAG, "$$ albumSetup remember parent entry")
        navController.getBackStackEntry(CreatingAlbumGraph)
    }
    val albumCreationViewModel: AlbumCreationViewModel = hiltViewModel(parentEntry)

    AlbumSetupScreen( onLeaveAlertClicked = { navController.popBackStack() })
}

@Composable
fun AlbumSetupScreen(onLeaveAlertClicked: () -> Unit) {
    Scaffold {}

    BackHandlingDialog( onLeaveClicked = onLeaveAlertClicked )
}

SetupNavGraph.kt:
@Serializable
object CreatingAlbumGraph

@Composable
fun SetupNavGraph() {
  NavHost( navController = navController, startDestination = SplashScreenDestination) {
     composable<SplashScreenDestination> {
       SplashScreen(navController)
     }
     composable<GalleryDestination>{
       GalleryRoute(navController)
    }
    creatingAlbumGraph(navController)
  }
}

    private fun NavGraphBuilder.creatingAlbumGraph(navController: NavHostController) {
        navigation<CreatingAlbumGraph>(startDestination = AlbumSetupDestination) {
            composable<AlbumSetupDestination> {
                AlbumSetupRoute(navController)
            }
            composable<FirstPhotoDestination> {
                FirstPhotoRoute(navController)
            }
        }
    }


remember(navController.currentBackStackEntry) is the wrong back stack entry to use in the remember since that changes immediately when you popBackStack. That means you pop, the remember re-runs, and CreatingAlbumGraph has already been popped off the graph.
Instead, you need to use the back stack entry passed to your composable as the key to your remember - that's the one that doesn't change for the entire lifetime of the composition:
composable<AlbumSetupDestination> { backStackEntry ->
    AlbumSetupRoute(backStackEntry, navController)
}

@Composable
fun AlbumSetupRoute(
    backStackEntry: NavBackStackEntry,
    navController: NavHostController
) {
    val parentEntry = remember(backStackEntry) {
        Log.d(TAG, "$$ albumSetup remember parent entry")
        navController.getBackStackEntry(CreatingAlbumGraph)
    }
    val albumCreationViewModel: AlbumCreationViewModel = hiltViewModel(parentEntry)

    AlbumSetupScreen( onLeaveAlertClicked = { navController.popBackStack() })
}

